# How to visualize prometheus histogram as frequency bar chart in grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have a prometheus histogram with buckets [100, 200, 500, 700, 900]. I just want to display the frequencies. However, prometheus histograms are cumulative and it seems that grafana panels are with respect to time. I didn't find an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Grafana's Heatmap panel: http://docs.grafana.org/features/panels/heatmap/